# installing eth-netstats

Tags: go-ethereum

I am installing eth-netstats on a private network. I configured everything as the docs suggested, however the eth-net-intelligence api complains about a connection refused error:

```
2017-10-18 08:59 -05:00: [wsc] =✘= Socket error: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.137.101:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.168.137.101',
  port: 80,
  type: 'error',
  target: 
   WebSocket {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: onerror] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _socket: null,
     _ultron: null,
     _closeReceived: false,
     bytesReceived: 0,
     readyState: 3,
     supports: { binary: true },
     extensions: null,
     _binaryType: 'arraybuffer',
     _isServer: false,
     url: 'ws://192.168.137.101/api/?_primuscb=Lylo2SH',
     protocolVersion: 13,
     _closeTimer: null,
     _closeCode: 1006 } }
```

The eth-netstats process is using only port 3000 , but not 80 (ws) or 443 (wss). I have been looking into the config and I can't find any parameter there that specifies the listening ip/port number for the websocket. Logically, there should be 2 ports open for listening, one for the browser and one for eth-net-intelligence-api to push the stats, but there is only 1 port, the 3000.

On the eth-net-intelligence-api I have this config file:

```
[
  {
    "name"              : "node-app",
    "script"            : "app.js",
    "log_date_format"   : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "merge_logs"        : false,
    "watch"             : false,
    "max_restarts"      : 10,
    "exec_interpreter"  : "node",
    "exec_mode"         : "fork_mode",
    "env":
    {
      "NODE_ENV"        : "production",
      "RPC_HOST"        : "localhost",
      "RPC_PORT"        : "8545",
      "LISTENING_PORT"  : "30303",
      "INSTANCE_NAME"   : "MY ETH",
      "CONTACT_DETAILS" : "1234567",
      "WS_SERVER"       : "ws://192.168.137.101",
      "WS_SECRET"       : "myethereum",
      "VERBOSITY"       : 2
    }
  }
]
```

What parameters do I have to modify in eth-netstats and eth-net-intelligence-api so the eth-net-intelligence process connects to the websocket of eth-netstats ???

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion around about how to run eth-netstats for a private ethereum network. I found when doing this (using geth v1.7.3) you don't actually have to run the eth-net-intelligence-api.

Simply run geth with the following command line argument when you start each instance (set ${ETHSTATS_URL} to whatever it needs to be - eg http://localhost:3000)

```
--ethstats <login>:<chosen_secret>@${ETHSTATS_URL}
```

Also ensure that --rpcaddr and --rpcapi arguments are set as well.

And then also run eth-netstats on the machine pointed to by the above URL, in the directory where you checked out and built it (as per these instructions https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-monitoring-on-local-cluster):

```
WS_SECRET=<chosen_secret> npm start
```

Then point your web browser at ${ETHSTATS_URL}:3000, and you will see the stats being updated from the node(s) in your private network.